# React Dropzone: TypeError: children is not a function

Tags: reactjs, npm, dropzone

I found some similar questions related to this, but they never gave a clear indication of what to do and ultimately resulting in more issues. Here is my code

```
  render(){
    return(
      <Dropzone>
        Drop Files Here
      </Dropzone>
    )
  }
}
export default Mockup
```

And this is exactly the error

```
TypeError: children is not a function
./node_modules/react-dropzone/dist/es/index.js/Dropzone<
```

Comment: What you should do is follow the documentation: https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone#refs it's got examples of what do when using the `<Dropzone />` component directly at the bottom of that "refs" section. You can copy/paste their code. Hint: it uses the render props pattern